# Why do I keep getting [BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe] no matter the number of workers in my Pool with multiprocessing lib in python3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, cpu, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use a Pool of workers python3's multiprocessing library to accelerate a CPU intensive task. I notice that no matter the number of workers in my pool, I always end up getting the following error :

> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

The code that leads to this error is the following:

```
def save_result(rincL):
    #Save results here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(8)
    allProcesses = []
    for i in range(60): 
        rincL = RINC_L(2, X_train, y_train[:,i].ravel(), X_test, y_test[:,i].ravel(), 6, i)
        allProcesses.append(p.apply_async(rincL.RINC_N, [0]))
    #Moved the two following lines based on suggestions in the comment
    #Still getting the same error.
    #p.close()
    #p.join()
    for process in allProcesses:
        save_result(process.get())
        time.sleep(1)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I also noticed that after a while of this program running. The number of processes jumps from 8 to a very high number. Something like 30 processes are spawned:
[image]

Comment: Try moving your `p.close()` and `p.join()` to the end of the file. The broken pipe suggests the other end is closed already when you try to access.

Comment: I keep getting the exact same error. @ThuYeinTun

Comment: My guess is that the parent process is dying for some reason. I would try to monitor it in some way (ps -ef, for example), and see if this hypothesis holds water.

Comment: Does the code run when you removed the pool? Is there any places where you use queue?

Comment: @ThuYeinTun YEs the code runs fine without the pool .. And no I am not using any queues.

Comment: @Roy2012 I monitored my processes and the main process is still alive so I don't think that is the problem .. I noticed something weird too. At some point the number of processes becomes abnormally high. I used a pool of only 8 processes but I end up getting like 30 processes after a while .. I updated my post to showcase this issue.

Comment: If the number of processes is going up, it might be because the parent process thinks that some of the child processes died, and spawns new processes.

Comment: Do you manage to reproduce this behavior with a smaller example? What happens if you replace the rincL function with dummy code?

Comment: @Roy2012 With a smaller example it does work. Is there an implicit timeout on the task submetted to a pool ?

Comment: Not that I know of. processes can run with their input and output for hours (and days). Do the child processes writing anything (or reading anything) from standard output (input)?

Comment: @Roy2012 Yes the child processes are just writing "Done" when they finish their job

Comment: @Roy2012 They are not getting anything from input though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The child processes were using too much memory and were being killed by the OS.